# Can a batch file run everything in the folder it's in?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, autohotkey

I use Autohotkey to replace some of the broken buttons on my mouse and to have an auto clicker and other quality of life hotkys and such, I have them in a folder with a batch file. I would like the bat file to open them all without having to type the names of the scripts one by one, sort of having an 'all' character like *.ahk. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I got the question , but if you want to run all `.ahk` files you can use something like this:

```
for %%a in (*.ahk) do start "" "%%~fa"
```